# Vector representation based on similarity

Tags: regression, machine-learning, regression-analysis

I have a set of points that I want to place in a N-dimensional space.

I only know the similarity between pairs of points, my final goal is to calculate a vector representation of each of those points, satisfying the similarity constraints.

Example:
$dist(A, B) = 0.8$
$dist(A, C) = 0.7$

$dist(B, C) = 0.4$

I need to get the coordinates of A, B, C in a N-dimensional space. What kind of tools should I look forward for solving that?

Comment: You should replace the word "similarity" by "(euclidean) distance". – This is an interesting, but very difficult problem.

Comment: ...or do you mean cosine similarity?

Comment: In my case this would be more related to cosine similarity, but if thinking about distances simplifies the problem I have no problem with that

Comment: My initial ideia to solve this problem was to use machine learning where the inputs are two points and the output is this similarity. If I use deep learning I can have an embedding matrix as the very first layer of the network and that would be my vectors representations. I just thought that was overkill and that a simpler mathematical approach should exist (maybe it's not that simple after all).

Comment: Are you required to find all possible solutions, or just a solution?

Comment: Just a solution

Answer (score 0):

Introduce the coordinate representation: $A = (a_1,...,a_N)$, $B=(b_1,...,b_N)$ and $C=(c_1,...,c_N)$. Then we can write down the three given equations as

$$\sum_{n=1}^N(a_n-b_n)^2=0.8^2,$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^N(a_n-c_n)^2=0.7^2,$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^N(b_n-c_n)^2=0.4^2.$$

It is clear that we only have $3$ equations but $3N$ unknows. Hence, you will need to introduce $3(N-1)$ additional constraints for $N\geq 2$. In order to reduce the complexity, you could shift all points by translation (does not change the distance) such that one of them coincides with the origin. For example, we could fix $A = (0,...,0)$ then we only are left with $2N$ unknows and you only need $2N-3$ additional constraints in order to determine the points. The additional constraints could be the distances to points with a known position. For each point, you would get $3$ additional constraints. So for the general case, you would need at least $N-1$ additional points in order to get a unique solution.